# How do I set the current component state from the data received as props from the parent component?

Tags: reactjs

The data received from the `Parent Component` can be used in the `render()` method of the `Child Component` but clearly, it's not possible to set the state in the render method as it creates an infinite loop. How do I `setState()` from the data received in props from the parent? I might have missed something but I also tried all the life-cycle components without much success.

For example,

```
import React from 'react';

class Parent extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
    let user = {name: John, age: 28};
    return(
      <Child user={user}>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: {} }
  }

  render()
  {
    const user = this.props.user;
    console.log(user); // --> [✓] Outputs {name: John, age: 28};
    // this.setState({ user }) // --> [✘] 

    return(
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

```
class Child extends React.Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: {} }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(this.state.user != nextProps.user){
         this.setState({ user:nextProps.user });
     }
  }
  render()
  {
    const user = this.props.user;
    console.log(user); // --> [✓] Outputs {name: John, age: 28};
    // this.setState({ user }) // --> [✘] 

    return(
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please wait 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the state initially in the constructor and then use the lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`. You can read more about lifecycle methods here: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle method, it will get called whenever any change happens to props values.

**[componentWillReceiveProps()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):**

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    /*compare new values and previous value first if they are not same then update the state*/
    if(condition)
       this.setState({users: newProps.users})
}
```